# What is the 'Deployed Resources' folder when I create a maven project with WAR packaging?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, web.xml

When I create a Maven project in Eclipse with the WAR packaging, I get a 'Deployed Resources' folder:

[image]

That folder has `webapp/WEB-INF...` and its contents such as web.xml.

It appears to be the same as `src/main/webapp`.

Should I modify the web.xml in this folder or the one in `src/main/webapp` ?

Answer (score 2):

Both point to the same file. It's just a different way of showing the same file in Eclipse's project explorer.